# Image doesn't cooperate with linking

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this simple task to work but I can't seem to do it. I have a twitter & facebook icon and I'm trying to them in my header region. The links work but the image doesn't show up. I have tried giving the section an "id" and setting the image as a background region but that still doesn't work:

```
<a href ="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/fbook.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
<a href ="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
```

I am testing it in chrome.

Comment: Could you post your CSS too, please?

Comment: Is your header file located in the root folder?

Comment: All the css is is the width and height which is given in the code. And the header is also in the index file. <header></header>

Comment: Should I just wrap them in div regions?

Comment: Try with <img ... width="50" height="50"> - IIRC the width and height for an IMG tag are expressed either as an integer value (expressing pixels) or a percentage. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#h-6.6

Comment: @juanrpozo is very correct here, width and height in html attributes should be expressed in integers without a unit suffix. If you're still having problems, mind creating a jsFiddle which demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you have not closed your image tag correctly.

```
<a href ="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.png" width="50px" height="50px"/></a>
```

Secondly check that if that image really exists or not in that location.

Comment: `IMG` is a void element. Void elements do not need closing. A `/` *may* be added just before the end of the start tag, but it has no effect.

Comment: Agree, I don't need to close it. And it works when I open the file remotely on my computer but when it goes on the hosting server, it doesn't work.